# My implementation of Bridson's algorithm Poisson-Disk Sampling seems to be stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: python, pygame

[A video by Sebastion Lague explained the Bridson's algorithm really well.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WcmyxyFO7o)

To oversimplify,

> 1. Create cell grid that has sides of radius/sqrt(2).
> 2. Place initial point and list as spawnpoint.
> 3. Place point into cell in grid.
> 4. For any spawnpoint, spawn a point between radius and 2*radius.
> 5. Look at the cells 2 units away from cell of new point.
> 6. If contains other points, compare distance.
> 7. If any point is closer to new point than the radius, new point is invalid.
> 8. If new point is valid, new point is listed as spawnpoint and placed into cell in grid.
> 9. If spawnpoint spawns too many invalid points, spawnpoint is removed and turns into point.
> 10. Repeat until no more spawnpoints exists.
> 11. Return points.

I basically written the same thing down in Python 3.7.2 and pygame 1.7~, but as said in the title, I'm stuck in recursive purgatory.

I used one Point() class for this algorithm, which might seem redundant given that pygame.Vector2() exists, but I needed some elements for a separate algorithm (Delaunay's with infinite vertices) that required this class to work.

For the sake of simplicity I'm going to cut away all the Delaunay-specific elements and show the bare-bones of this class that is needed for this algorithm:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def DistanceToSquared(self,other):
        return (self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2
```

The code that is related to the Bridson's algorithm is:

```py
def PoissonDiskSampling(width, height, radius, startPos = None, spawnAttempts = 10):

    if startPos == None:
        startPos = [width//2,height//2]

    cellSize = radius / math.sqrt(2)
    cellNumberX = int(width // cellSize + 1)  # Initialise a cells grid for optimisation
    cellNumberY = int(height // cellSize + 1)
    cellGrid = [[None for x in range(cellNumberX)] for y in range(cellNumberY)]

    startingPoint = Point(startPos[0],startPos[1]) # Add an iniial point for spawning purposes
    cellGrid[startingPoint.x//radius][startingPoint.y//radius] = startingPoint

    points = [startingPoint] # Initialise 2 lists tracking all points and active points
    spawnpoints = [startingPoint]

    while len(spawnpoints) > 0:

        spawnIndex = random.randint(0,len(spawnpoints)-1)
        spawnpoint = spawnpoints[spawnIndex]

        spawned = False
        for i in range(spawnAttempts):

            r = random.uniform(radius,2*radius)
            radian = random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
            newPoint = Point(spawnpoint.x + r*math.cos(radian),
                            spawnpoint.y + r*math.sin(radian))
            if 0 <= newPoint.x <= width and 0 <= newPoint.y <= height:
                isValid = True
            else:
                continue

            newPointIndex = [int(newPoint.x//cellSize), int(newPoint.y//cellSize)]
            neighbours = FindNeighbours(cellNumberX,cellNumberY,newPointIndex,cellGrid)

            for neighbour in neighbours:
                if newPoint.DistanceToSquared(neighbour) < radius**2:
                    isValid = False
                    break

            if isValid:
                points.append(newPoint)
                spawnpoints.append(newPoint)
                spawned = True
                break
            else:
                continue

        if spawned == False:
            spawnpoints.remove(spawnpoint)

    return points

def FindNeighbours(cellNumberX, cellNumberY, index, cellGrid):
    neighbours = []
    for cellX in range(max(0,(index[0]-2)), min(cellNumberX,(index[1]+2))):
        for cellY in range(max(0,(index[0]-2)), min(cellNumberY,(index[1]+2))):
            if cellGrid[cellX][cellY] != None:
                neighbours.append(cellGrid[cellX][cellY])
    return neighbours
```

Please help.

Comment: What is your test case? Which parameters did you use for PoissonDiskSampling()?
Also, please fix your identation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably most important step is missing in your code:

> 8. If new point is valid, new point is listed as spawnpoint and **placed into cell in grid**.

I suggest to add the point to the `cellGrid` if it is valid:

```py
if isValid:

    cellGrid[newPointIndex[0]][newPointIndex[1]] = newPoint

    points.append(newPoint)
    spawnpoints.append(newPoint)
    spawned = True
    break
```

Further, you have to verify if the cell with the index `newPointIndex` is not already occupied before a point can be add:

```py
newPointIndex = [int(newPoint.x/cellSize), int(newPoint.y/cellSize)]
if cellGrid[newPointIndex[0]][newPointIndex[1]] != None:
    continue

neighbours = FindNeighbours(cellNumberX,cellNumberY,newPointIndex,cellGrid)
```

---

Finally there is an issue in the function `FindNeighbours`. `range(start, stop)` creates a range for x in `start <= x < stop`.
So the stop has to be `index[0]+3` rather than `index[0]+2`.

Further the ranges which control the 2 nested `for` loops, run both from `x-2` to `y+2` rather than from `x-2` to `x+2` respectively from `y-2` to `y+2`:

> ```py
> for cellX in range(max(0,(index[0]-2)), min(cellNumberX,(index[1]+2))):
>    for cellY in range(max(0,(index[0]-2)), min(cellNumberY,(index[1]+2)))
> ```

The fixed function has to be:

```py
def FindNeighbours(cellNumberX, cellNumberY, index, cellGrid):
    neighbours = []
    for cellX in range(max(0, index[0]-2), min(cellNumberX, index[0]+3)):
        for cellY in range(max(0, index[1]-2), min(cellNumberY, index[1]+3)):
            if cellGrid[cellX][cellY] != None:
                neighbours.append(cellGrid[cellX][cellY])
    return neighbours
```

---

See the result, for a size of 300 x 300 and a radius of 15:

[image]

---

An even better result can be achieve, if always the 1st point of `spawnpoints` is used to rather than a random point:

```py
# spawnIndex = random.randint(0,len(spawnpoints)-1)
spawnIndex = 0 # 0 rather than random
spawnpoint = spawnpoints[spawnIndex]
```

[image]